# Oracle functions using Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, function

How can I call an Oracle function from Hibernate 3.6, without sending a SQL query? Or maybe, can I mix the SQL query (just for the function) with Criteria?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, this can be done using Formula annotation:

```
@Entity
public class A {
   @Column(name ="a1")
   private int a1;

   @Column(name ="a2")
   private int a2;

   @Formula("myFunction(a1)")
   private int a3;
   .....
}
```

And in the Criteria:

```
Criteria cr = getInstanciaCriteria(A.class); 
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("a3", 1));
```