# Hibernate Mapping Sql function to generate Primary key

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

In my project I am using oracle sql function to generate the primary keys (our client provides the Database and we are not allowed to change them) the generated id are something like this

prefix-1001, prefix-1002 and so on.

The problem is hibernate only support sequences to generate the PKs.
I have taken the reference of
[Oracle functions using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117923/oracle-functions-using-hibernate)
but at last it didn't work. I know I can achieve this using Native Sql query but is there any less complex way to do it.
I am writing the entity code like this

```
@Id
@Formula("GETCATEGORYID()")
private int id;
private String name;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate: How specify custom sequence generator class name using annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631800/hibernate-how-specify-custom-sequence-generator-class-name-using-annotations)

Comment: You didn't understand the question I want to use sql function to generate ID in hibernate